# Clickable zone of Hamburger icon in Toolbar is not accurate

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am facing a problem that *I couldn't solve* by myself.

I couldn't open my **Navigation Drawer** using **Hamburger icon** in the toolbar, but I found that clicking the area above the icon could open it.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Clickable zone]

In the image above, I can **open** the Navigation Drawer **only** if I click somewhere in the **red area**, otherwise nothing will happen.

OnCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupMainViews();
    configureToolBar();
    configureDrawerLayout();
    configureNavigationView();
}
```

configureToolBar:

```
private void configureToolBar(){
    this.tbMain = findViewById(R.id.tbMain);
    setSupportActionBar(tbMain);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

configureDrawerLayout:

```
private void configureDrawerLayout(){
    dlMain = findViewById(R.id.dlMain);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dlMain, tbMain,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
    dlMain.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dlMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbackground">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tbMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"/>

        //other views...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvSide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/sideview_header"
        app:menu="@menu/sidemenu_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an emulator by any chance? I find they have pretty bad accuracy when it comes to clicks. If you are that would likely be the issue.

Comment: I thought about that at first and used my phone to check it, but the problem is still there.

Comment: you should look though this link: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#java and make sure all you steps to set up the hamburger menu are correct, it may be that the area of the hamburger is overlapping the the clickable area.

Comment: for onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item), I already tried that without any success. I'll check if my steps are as mentioned in your link.